# Deploy Angular2 App to Tomcat8 - Routing does not seems to work

Tags: angular, tomcat8, angular-cli

I'm facing a strange issue trying to deploy my Angular2 app to tomcat8.

First of all the context : 
 - I use Angular Cli to assit my build process.
 - The apps runs perfectly locally with the server : ng serve
 - ng build makes my dist/ dir with all prod ressources
 - I created a gulp task to create a WAR in order to deploy properly the app to Tomcat.
 - the war is deployed to tomcat webapps directoy

My app URI is like that : https:\www.myexample.com\myapp\

Home uri is working perfectly; 
The problem starts when trying to use Angular2 routing; for instance 
https:\www.myexample.com\myapp\myroute.

Tomcats thinks that it is a new webapp dir and does not makes any forwarding do https:\www.myexample.com\myapp\index.html

I have seen several post speaking about this kind of behaviour but so far; I haven't seen any solutions.

does anyone has a clue / idea how I can overcome this issue to run properly my angular2 app on tomcat8 ?

Thanks for support.

Comment: Try adding `RouterModule.foRoot(useHash: true)`. If it works this way than your server needs to be configure to support HTML5 pushState.

Comment: Please add this as an answer as it saves my day @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: If shussons answer helps feel free to accept his.

Answer (score 3):

You need to rewrite the urls to serve `index.html` unless the dir or file exists.

Configure Tomcat to use the rewrite valve https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html

Then add the something like below to the `rewrite.config` file:

```
# If dir or asset exists go to it
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# Rewrite all other urls to use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Comment: Where should I put the rewrite.config?

Comment: Is there a way to do this server side, in a Java Controller? I think I have a similar issue, my-app runs fine from ng serve, but when I bundle it in a war, browser refreshs stops working, if it involves a route such as /home or /inbox. I get a 404 with a browser refresh, if there is a route involved. Routing works fine if I am clicking around in the app. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Adding `RouterModule.forRoot(useHash: true)` switches to URLs using `#` which works with every server.

To use HTML5 pushState (Angular default) your server needs to be configured to support it.

For a comparison of both styles see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles

Answer (score 1):

Angular (2+) supports two types of Routing Strategies – `HashLocationStrategy` and `PathLocationStrategy`. `PathLocationStrategy` is the default configuration when you build an application using the angular CLI. `PathLocationStrategy` is having lot of advantages over the `HashLocationStrategy` and is the recommended configuration which is discussed in the docs [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles).

The drawback of `PathLocationStrategy` is that it needs specific configuration to be done at the server side. If this configuration is not done at the server end, then it leads to `404` when deep links are accessed directly. Also this configuration depends on which server is being used.

For fixing the deep link issue when deploying angular application (with PathLocationStrategy routing) on apache tomcat server (8, 9) -

1. Configure the RewriteValve in server.xml
2. Write the rewrite rule in rewrite.config

server.xml -

```
...
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />

...
      </Host>
...
```

rewrite.config - (note - /hello/ is the context path of the angular app on tomcat)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} !-f
RewriteRule ^/hello/(.*) /hello/index.html
```

I have documented this issue in my article - [Fixing deep linking issue – Deploying angular application on Tomcat server](http://codedumpster.nithinbiliya.com/deep-linking-issue-angular-application-tomcat-server/)